# How to have a method with an argument class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an assignment where I am supposed to define a class and have a method that would use the distance formula on two given a points(x,y,z). I have already worked out the first point, the problem is the second point since the user can input the point or leave it blank which would have default point of (0,0,0). The relevant section of the code is:

````
# Maximum value
MAX_VAL = 10000

# Minimum value
MIN_VAL = -10000

def __init__(self, x, y, z):
    # Check inputs
    if not 0 <= x <= self.MAX_VAL:
        print ('Invalid x_value')
    if not 0 <= y<= self.MAX_VAL:
        print ('Invalid y_value')
    if not 0 <= z <= self.MAX_VAL:
        print ('Invalid z_value')

    self._x_value = x
    self._y_value = y
    self._z_value = z
def get_distance_between_points(self,x_coord=0,y_coord=0,z_coord=0):   
  return sqrt((self._x_value-x_coord)**2+(self._y_value-x_coord)**2+(self._z_value-x_coord))```
````

I was hoping to call the function as :

```
point_a=Point(3,2,9)
point_b=Point(2,9,7)
print(point_a.get_distance_between_points(point_b))
print(point_a.get_distance_between_points())
```

The first print function would have given points then the second print function would be using the default point (0,0,0). Any thoughts on how I can proceed? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You want to call ``point_a.get_distance_between_points(point_b)`` but you define the function to accept three parameters. Does this clue help?

Comment: @Prasanth I think I know what you mean but I tried defining it with only one parameter. But I don't know what to put in the parameter. I have been spinning my head on what I must put in it.

Comment: @Monsi `point=None` then `if point is None: point = Point(0, 0, 0)`

Comment: Your code also seems to have a problem with not using the `MIN_VAL`. Don't you think that each of `x`, `y`, `z` must range between `[MIN_VAL, MAX_VAL]`. That is: `self.MIN_VAL <= x <= self.MAX_VAL`? Currently, you are using `0` instead of `MIN_VAL`.

Comment: point_a is an instance of Point(). I like the approach of @Prasanth, but then you need add the method for Point() get_distance_between_points(point_b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass a `Point` to your method, with a default value of `None`:

```
def get_distance_between_points(self,other_point=None):
    if other_point is None:
        x, y, z = 0, 0, 0
    else:
        x, y, z = other_point.x_value, other_point.y_value, other_point.z_value

  return sqrt((self._x_value-x)**2+(self._y_value-y)**2+(self._z_value-z))
```

Comment: lol it was that easy hahaha. Thank you for that did not think about using `None`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can set default arguments in the definition of the function.

```
  def get_distance_between_points(self, pnt=None):
    if pnt == None:
      pnt = Point(0,0,0)
    return <the usual logic here>
```